# Python: Replace Item

Tags: python, string, replace, nltk

I have the following:

```
[('The', 'NNP'), ('map', 'NNP'), ('is', 'VBZ'), 
('way', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ('using', 'VBG'), ('tool', 'NN'), 
(',', ','), ('skill', 'VBG'), ('and', 'CC')]
```

And, I need to replace the string with 'NN' every time it's paired with 'NN'. So the output should be:

```
[('The', 'NNP'), ('map', 'NNP'), ('is', 'VBZ'), 
('NN', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ('using', 'VBG'), ('NN', 'NN'), 
(',', ','), ('skill', 'VBG'), ('and', 'CC')]
```

I tried the following, but it won't replace the item. please help!

```
for s in sentence:
    if s[1] == 'NN':
        s[0] == 'NN'
print(sentence)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuples cannot be assigned to - they're immutable. One option is to re-build your POS tags list from scratch.

```
pos_tags = [(x if y != 'NN' else y, y) for x, y in pos_tags]
```

If not this, then, re-assign your list items.

```
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(pos_tags):
    if y == 'NN':
        pos_tags[i] = ('NN', 'NN')
```

```
print(pos_tags)

[('A', 'NNP'),
 ('Discourse', 'NNP'),
 ('is', 'VBZ'),
 ('NN', 'NN'),
 ('of', 'IN'),
 ('using', 'VBG'),
 ('NN', 'NN'),
 (',', ','),
 ('thinking', 'VBG'),
 ('and', 'CC'),
 ('acting', 'VBG')]
```